# How to show spinkit when user press on marker on google maps? (flutter_spinkit)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement the library flutter_spinkit and everything seems to work fine, except for the actual popup with the spinning circle/whatever you wanna show in the UI.

I'm trying to get it to work when user clicks on a marker on the google maps, but nothing happens. I definitely lack experience in how to load another widget over the home-widget.

So, how can I get this to work?

This is the code I tried with:

```
    class ShowLoadingKit extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitCircle(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 150.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And calling as this, (from another class):

```
    void _showLoadingSpinCircle(String lat, String lng) {
    //_onMarkerTapped(lat, lng);

    ShowLoadingKit();
  }
```

Shouldn't the widget appear with that call? I'm confused..

Comment: Where do you want the loader to be shown?  Maybe you missed a `return` like `return ShowLoadingKit();`.

Comment: Thats right! Now it works, thank you sir! @10101010

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed a `return`.

```
return ShowLoadingKit();
```